# What troops should I train?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have level 8 barracks and 180 housing space. What troops should I train... also lvl 3 spell factory and lvl 7 town hall. Im not a farmer im trying to get into gold. I also like clan wars and I need troops to winn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm right around where you are now, and this is what I've had success with:

- Roughly 6-8 Wall Breakers
- Roughly 15-20 Giants

Of your remaining housing space:

- 60% are Archers
- 20% are Goblins
- 20% are Barbarians

Spell-wise, I tend to take Lightning almost exclusively.  Dropping a couple of those in a heavy-defense area can make a fight significantly easier.

Now, a lot of people ask "what troop mix should I use?" but just as important is how they're deployed and what targets you pick.

My battle strategy follows.  I tend to send the Giants in first, with the goal of taking down Mortars and Wizard Towers.  Ideally, you want their first target to be a Mortar.  Mortars will *pwn* your grunts.  As the Giants approach the first wall, drop wall breakers, which will tend to not get targeted since the Giants are in the way.

After you've distracted or dealt with the defenses in an area, drop Archers, and then Barbarians and/or Goblins.  Try to space them out a bit so that any stray group-hit fire will miss them.

When it comes to picking targets, my associate EBongo [has a good guide on the subject.](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/5-quick-tips-for-clash-of-clans-farming/)  Checking your defense log for easy revenge wins and watching for AFK/idle players are two solid tips from that guide.

It's also important to look at a base and plan out how much it will cost you to get the resources, versus how much resources you're likely to get from it.  Many bases are just too big and complex to really be worth the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

With those giants I'd place them first heading towards archer/wizard towers on two sides, since the archers towers rate of fire is quick. With those wizards place them behind the giants, as the giants start losing health place the heal spells. And with the goblins place them by the resource collectors.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is all dragons and 3 rage spells. When the dragons reach the air defences, drop the rage spells on the dragons. That is a 100% victory right there

Answer (score 0):

I attack with 2 wallbreakers,2 goblins, 10 giants, 1 balloons, and 9 archers. First I deploy 2 goblins to get rid of the traps. Then, I deploy 10 giants and the 2 wallbreakers once the giants are near the walls. After they destroy the defenses, I deploy all 9 archers to speed up the game. I use the balloon in case of emergency. Later i get 3 stars.

I am at th4.

goblins,giants,archers lv 2. wallbreaker and balloon r lv 1

Answer (score 0):

I'm at TH5. I use 16 giants, 20 archers , 4 barbarians, 3 balloons, 1 wizard and 1 lightning spell. First check if there are clan castle troops with your archers and if there are then kill them with your archers. Then deploy your giants and wipe the defences. After wiping the air defence, deploy your balloons. Use the barbarians and goblins to clean up.